# How to bind VueJS methods scope to Firebase Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

How can I bind VueJs methods scope to returned Firebase Promise? in order to call VueJS Modal

```
   login: function () {
            fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.signIn.email, this.signIn.password)
                .then(function (user) {
                    if (!user.emailVerified) {
                        this.$modal.show('email_verification', {
                            text: 'Please verify your email'
                        })
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                })
        }
```

Now, here is error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$modal' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Use an arrow function in your promise callbacks so that `this` is bound lexically

```
login: function () {
            fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.signIn.email, this.signIn.password)
                .then( (user) => {
                    if (!user.emailVerified) {
                        this.$modal.show('email_verification', {
                            text: 'Please verify your email'
                        })
                    }
                },  (error) => {
                    console.log(error.message);
                })
        }
```

Or declare a `var self` pointing the vue instance inside the method and use `self` to use  vue instance as the callbacks will now have a closure over the `var self` variable

```
login: function () {
           var self = this;
            fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.signIn.email, this.signIn.password)
                .then(function (user) {
                    if (!user.emailVerified) {
                        self.$modal.show('email_verification', {
                            text: 'Please verify your email'
                        })
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                })
        }
```